# SDL window updates slowly if I don't move my mouse

Tags: c++, loops, sdl-2

I recently tried to implement OneLoneCoder's [simple 3d Graphics Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih20l3pJoeU), from his Code-It-Yourself series, on SDL2. So I made some triangles that move on the window, but these triangles would appear to move at a slower framerate when I left my mouse completely still, and then move at their normal framerate if I started to move my mouse.

You see, to animate these triangles I used some while loops, something like this:

```
while (true) {
    // Black Background
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    // Custom function that draws a triangle using SDL_RenderDrawLine()
    drawTriangle(renderer, triangle);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); // updates the pixels on the renderer

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            goto Exit;
    }
}
```

Pretty standard, right?

Here is an example of some code that has this exact same issue:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"SDL.h"


struct vec {
    float x, y;

    vec ( float x, float y)
        : x(x), y(y)
    {}

    vec () {}
};

struct triangle { 
    vec p[3];

    triangle() {}
};


void drawTriangle(SDL_Renderer* r, const triangle& tri) {
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(r, tri.p[0].x, tri.p[0].y, tri.p[1].x, tri.p[1].y);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(r, tri.p[1].x, tri.p[1].y, tri.p[2].x, tri.p[2].y);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(r, tri.p[2].x, tri.p[2].y, tri.p[0].x, tri.p[0].y);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint16_t width = 400;
    uint16_t height = 300;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0) { std::cout << "SDL_INIT FAILED\nERROR: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl; }
    
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Test :)", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    
    if (window == NULL) { std::cout << "SDL_WINDOW FAILED\nERROR: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl; }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);


    triangle myTri;

    myTri.p[0] = vec( width * 0.5, 0);
    myTri.p[1] = vec( width * 0.333, height * 0.2);
    myTri.p[2] = vec( width * 0.666, height * 0.2);


    while (true) {

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        myTri.p[0].y += 0.01f;
        myTri.p[1].y += 0.01f;
        myTri.p[2].y += 0.01f;        
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        drawTriangle(renderer, myTri);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                goto Exit;
        }
    }

    Exit:

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try somehow limiting FPS.

Comment: On what platform did you observe this?

Comment: @Davis Herring My computer is a 32-bit Windows 7 machine, oh and it doesn't have a dedicated graphics card, hence the SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE on my example.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried capping my FPS using some code that I ended up seeing everywhere, something like this: [link](https://thenumbat.github.io/cpp-course/sdl2/08/08.html#cap), also tried using SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC, although this one was kind of a long shot, perhaps I have to take another approach?